# Linq query return the identical records by id

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have an SQL database view that contains a multiple records . Some ID are duplicated but have different records.

```
Supervisorid     Department    EmployeeName
..
327               Sales          Andrea
327               Analytics      Richard
327               IT             Bob
..
```

Whenever I use LinQ Query like where `Supervisorid = 327`

```
var currentRecords = db.vSupervisors.Where(x => x.SupervisorID == Supervisorid).toList();
```

It does brings me 3 records but it always will be the 1st record that will be duplicated 
327               Sales          Andrea

I Believe the problem is that `Supervisorid` is not a primary key. How should my query look like?

Comment: Is supervisorid supposed to be a primary key? That is, should every row have a unique Id? I think we need more info about what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: Do you mean you get 3 copies of same record instead of 3 different records with same Supervisor Id ?

Comment: What's your question?  Are you trying to get the first record? Or all people under a certain supervisor?  Or are you saying `currentRecords` contains the same record three times?

Comment: No supervisor is not suppose to be primary key. I get a data from the View.  I just need to retrieve all records that belong to specific Supervisorid. If Supervisorid is not duplicated I have no problem. In case of 2 or more records I have this problem.

Comment: all people under certain supervisor

Comment: "Do you mean you get 3 copies of same record instead of 3 different records with same Supervisor Id" - yes that the problem . Just need all 3 records.

Comment: when you say, you get 3 copies of same record...how do you do the comparison ?

Comment: I think something is amiss here, SQL server, EF, or any ORM should not be doing this (and id be surprised if it were), my suspicion is you are pointing to the wrong data base, or you have the wrong assumption about whats being returned... you can look at the generated SQL and run that query directly on the database, but my gut feeling is you are looking at the data wrong, once its being returned

Comment: I do a visual comparison in debugger and search records with the same ID in the database.

Comment: Will need to check my code. I have simplified the problem. But I cannot put the whole code. Just wanted to check if the absence of primary key can be a problem there. Thanks  everyone !

Comment: No, this shouldn't happen, there is something else going on

Comment: Is this EF, or EF Core, or LINQ to SQL? If EF / EF Core, your model could be defaulting to `Supervisorid` being a primary key and consolidating any requests. For EF Core, only version 3 supports [entity types without primary keys for views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#query-types-are-consolidated-with-entity-types) or in EF Core 2.1 there were [query types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types).

Answer (score 0):

Check the view definition in SQL. If the definition of the view contains an error like a bad join, it could easily explain this behaviour. Try running the SQL in a query window and see if you get consistent results. If so, correct the view definition in SQL.